# How to run this C++ code in ubuntu?

Tags: c++

I have compiled this code: https://github.com/vbdaga/Rabbit-Cipher/blob/master/rabbit.cpp
with `g++ rabbit.cpp -o Rabbit` but there are nowhere instructions on how to pass the arguments. I see only `getline` which do not help... I use Ubuntu 22.04.2 if that helps... Does anyone has any idea how to proceed?

Comment: Run the program with ./Rabbit ... You can add arguments by running ./Rabbit foot ears ... Then in argv[1] will contain foot and argv[2] will contain ears ... Ubuntu version doesn't matter. If you need more details, update your question

Comment: Have you looked at the source code file `rabbit.cpp`? it's not very large. It looks like it doesn't actually use command line arguments - it just reads from `input.txt` (by `freopen`ing it as `stdin`)

Comment: It builds an ```output.txt``` around 2.1GB. Something is wrong....

Comment: @just_learning I suggest you edit `input.txt` and reduce the `plaintext_size` to 4, same as the example in the `README.md` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rabbit.cpp` file appears to contain a minimal test program for the encryption library - you can pass it arguments, but it will ignore them:

```
$ g++ -Wunused-parameter -o Rabbit rabbit.cpp 
rabbit.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
rabbit.cpp:9:14: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’ [-Wunused-parameter]
    9 | int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
      |          ~~~~^~~~
rabbit.cpp:9:32: warning: unused parameter ‘argv’ [-Wunused-parameter]
    9 | int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
      |                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
```

Instead, it reads parameters from the `input.txt` file:

```
key:
2115 55464 876543 3213 6456 79 6546 312
IV:
654897 32135
plaintext_size:
300000000
```

(well *technically* it reads from `std::cin`, after reopening `input.txt` on the standard input stream). As shipped, it doesn't provide any means to enter plaintext - it simply stuffs the `plaintext` vector with `plaintext_size` zero bytes:

```
    vector <unsigned int> plaintext;
    int len;
    cin>>len;
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
            int x;
            //cin>>x;
            plaintext.push_back(0);
    }
```

With the given `plaintext_size` of 300000000 that will produce an extremely large ciphertext output.

If you want to verify that the program works as intended, I suggest you modify `input.txt` corresponding to the example in the `README.md` file:

```
### Example

key1 = [0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000]

plain_text = [0000 0000 0000 0000 ]

iv = [0000 0000]

cipher_text = [ED B7 05 67 37 5D CD 7C D8 95 54 F8 5E 27 A7 C6]
```

i.e.

```
$ cat input.txt
key:
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
IV:
0000 0000
plaintext_size:
4
```

Then `./Rabbit` should produce the following `output.txt`:

```
$ cat output.txt 
01100111000001011011011111101101
01111100110011010101110100110111
11111000010101001001010111011000
11000110101001110010011101011110
```

which you can confirm contains the expected ciphertext bytes for example using

```
$ perl -ne 'printf "%X\n", unpack("L", pack("B*", $_))' output.txt 
EDB70567
375DCD7C
D89554F8
5E27A7C6
```